# How to send the form-data directly to controller instead of retriving one by one

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot

I am involved in a project which uses Spring for backend and jquery for the frontend and ajax to establish communication between them.

I'm stuck while posting a form data through ajax.

I need to send the form data to the controller but when I'm sending directly the form data it's getting `400` error but if the same thing I do by retrieving input one by one and sending the data, it's successfully getting saved.

Suppose my form contains more than 30 fields and I don't think it'll be a convenient way to retrieve the fields one by one and send to the server

I'm supposed to send the whole form data in a single shot.

### Code I'm getting `400`

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#save").click(function(){

        alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
        var url= "http://localhost:8080/CurdAppBackend/emp/save";
        $.post({
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify($('form[name=loginform]').serialize()),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert("SAVED")
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    });

});
```

### The same code successfully saving in DB

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#save").click(function(){

        alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
        var url= "http://localhost:8080/CurdAppBackend/emp/save";
        $.post({
            url: url,
            data: {
                "empName":$("#empName").val(),
                "empMob":$("#empMob").val(),
                "empDesg":$("#empDesg").val(),
                "unit":$("#unit").val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert("SAVED")
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Now Just observe. I've referred some documentation also tried various way to send the form data to server but all in vain except the manual one by retrieving one by one.

### LoginForm

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Add Employee</div>
                    <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Need
                            Help?</a></div>
                </div>

                <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body">

                    <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                    <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="loginform">

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <input id="empName" type="text" class="form-control" name="empName" value=""
                                placeholder="employee name">
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input id="empMobile" type="text" class="form-control" name="empMobile"
                                placeholder="mobile">
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input id="empDesg" type="text" class="form-control" name="empDesg"
                                placeholder="designation">
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input id="unit" type="text" class="form-control" name="unit"
                                placeholder="unit">
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                            <!-- Button -->

                            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                <a id="save" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Save </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Controller

```
@PostMapping("/save") 
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> insertRecord(@ModelAttribute @Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDTO dto) {
        EmployeeDTO dtoo= null;

        dtoo= service.insertEmp(dto);


        return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO>(dtoo,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Can anyone have any idea how to send the form data directly instead of retrieving it?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` for `$('form[name=loginform]').serialize()` is __not needed__

Comment: even then also 400

Comment: Refer This  : https://www.boraji.com/spring-4-mvc-jquery-ajax-form-submit-example

Comment: Just simply call `serialize()` by form id like `$("#loginform").serialize()`. And remove `@ModelAttribute` annotation from server call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){

        alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
        var data = $('form[name=loginform]').serializeArray(); 
        var url= "http://localhost:8080/CurdAppBackend/emp/save";
        $.post({
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert("SAVED")
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    });

});
```

When you want to convert the data to Json , `serializeArray()` is more suitable match as the data is structured and it passing through a `JSON.stringfy()` will produce a Json String. The Serialize() will create an encoded string but it is not suitable for use with the jquery ajax call,as the POST request param data expects a JSON as you have set the content-type as `"application/json"` .

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/anantha005/wj0c4rdx/2/

Reference : https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/